# window addEventListener keydown not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, keycode

I am coding a game where a cube moves across the screen when you press the arrow keys down. But it doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

```js
var playerElement = document.getElementById('playerEl');
var playerY = 0;
var playerX = 0;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      playerX -= 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%);";
      break;
    case 38:
      playerY -= 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%);";
      break;
    case 39:
      playerX += 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%);";
      break;
    case 40:
      playerY += 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%);";
      break;
  }
}, true);
```

```css
#playerEl {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(1%, 1%);
}
```

```html
<body style="height:100vh;width:100vw;">
  <div id="playerEl"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the `transform` `style` property using javascript, you don't have to add a `;` in the string.

It should be done like this:

```
playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%)";
```

Here's your code without the `;` in the `transform` strings.

```js
var playerElement = document.getElementById('playerEl');
var playerY = 0;
var playerX = 0;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      playerX -= 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%)"; // Removed semi-colon from string
      break;
    case 38:
      playerY -= 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%)"; // Removed semi-colon from string
      break;
    case 39:
      playerX += 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%)"; // Removed semi-colon from string
      break;
    case 40:
      playerY += 100;
      playerElement.style.transform = "translate(" + playerX + '%,' + playerY + "%)"; // Removed semi-colon from string
      break;
  }
}, true);
```

```css
#playerEl {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(1%, 1%);
}
```

```html
<body style="height:100vh;width:100vw;">
  <div id="playerEl"></div>
</body>
```